In this example of colon usage, what would you call the sentence left of the colon?

Example below this line:

The RTO demonstrates:
(a) how it identifies the facilities, resources and equipment required to deliver the
training product, including which of these will be provided by the RTO or third parties
(b) where facilities, resources and equipment are provided by the RTO or third parties,
how it ensures:

(i) the ongoing suitability and safety of the facilities, resources and equipment for the
VET student cohort
(ii) that VET students have access to the resources and equipment they need to participate
in the training and assessment

(c) where training involves work-integrated learning, work placements, or other community-
based learning, strategies are in place to manage any risks associated with these
facilities, resources and equipment.

The above excerpt comes from draft revised standards for RTOs from the Australian Government's Department of Employment and Workplace Relations.


What do you call the element of the sentence left of the colon when forming a "branch" sentence?
When using a colon to nest sentences as in the above example, what do you call the parent element? the part to the left of the colon, or conversely what would you call the child element to the right of the colon?
In the example above we have:

The RTO demonstrates:
where facilities, resources and equipment are provided by the RTO or third parties, how it ensures:

From a programming background, I would describe everything left of the colon as the parent in a parent/child relationship, or as a node inside a branch along a tree.
By "branch sentence" I am referring to parent-child, parent-child relationship through every indentation in the sentence structure (to the exclusion of any sibling nodes), as an example...
Using point (ii) as an example, I would interpret (ii) as the last node in a branch starting from "The RTO demonstrates", then including (b) and ending with (ii)

The RTO demonstrates where facilities, resources and equipment are provided by the RTO or third parties, how it ensures that VET students have access to the resources and equipment they need to participate in the training and assessment.

What have I tried?
The following link points to key-value pairs which I do not believe apply to the above example.
I am not asking from a programming perspective, I want to know what I call the element should I need to quote a standard inside its full context.
What is the X called in the "X:Y" identifier?
cheers,

That part is the lead-in, or lead-in sentence if it forms a whole sentence.

This website (from medical organization the Cochrane Community) uses the term "platform phrase" for the text preceding a list, but I can't see anybody else using that terminology so I guess it's not a common grammatical term.

In some terminologies, the terms [subject] + [predicator] would be used for any such strings like 'The RTO demonstrates'. In this type of list, there follows a bulleted compound predicate (with the colon to indicate the list nature).
